# How to set the PayPal account details inf the PayPal PHP SDK?

Tags: php, paypal

I am making a store with the PayPal PHP-SDK, and I am wondering about where the payments go. There are no options in the config to put in account details, nor do I see where you would put them in anywhere else. So do payments just automatically go to the account that you have your PayPal developer account created with? I really need to know this, because I am making this site for a client, and I don't exactly want all of their sales going to my account...

Comment: I haven't used their SDK, but there should be a config file somewhere that has the credentials in it.  You may be interested in checking out my [PHP library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) instead.  I've gotten lots of good feedback from people who prefer it over the PayPal provided SDK for exactly this sort of reason...just a lot more intuitive and easy to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, whenever transactions are made using the REST API, the funds go by default to the PayPal account that was used to get credentials from developer.paypal.com to create the application and get the client_id/client_secret pair. This is independent of the particular library or sdk that you use to access the APIs. Configuring the receiver of payments is certainly in the works but is currently not possible using the REST API.

If something is left unclear on the officially supported API, please do open an issue and start a conversation on https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I opened up an issue on the repo requesting that the feature be added, not realizing that you were a developer on the project. For now I guess I will resort to the less customizable payment button. I look forward to seeing this addition to future (hopefully near ;) ) versions of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to setup a different app for each merchant. That would give you a different clientId and Secret Pair for each merchant.

Or the merchant could setup an app in their account. The reason being, if they want to enable "Business Account" services, they would be able to update their systems accordingly.